# How do I Programmatically link an Excel table to a Powerpoint 2003 Chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have charts built in [powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint) where the data was manually pasted into the charts' dataSheets. I

I would like the user to be able to specify which excel file he would like to use and have the code link (or import) the data.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: did you try anything on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Copy data from Excel, and then use Paste Special. See [here](http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/photosgraphicsclipart/ss/070805excelchrt_2.htm)